# How to check if saveAndFlush() successfully updated the entity parameters in the database while using JpaRespository?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

I am currently developing a small Spring Rest + Spring Data application and the requirement is to update address (String address) of an User if the user already exists in the database. Now once I retrieve the user entity from database, I am setting the address string in the entity and calling saveAndFlush() on the entity. Now, here is my confusion. Incase this update operation is not successful (due to any reason whatsoever), I want to raise my own custom exception.

- How do I check if the update operation was successful? I know saveAndFlush will return an updated entity, and I am using the entity to check if it is same as the entity retrieved from database earlier. But this is failing when I am providing same address for the update. Is there any other way to check?
- What exception could be thrown from saveAndFlush() in between the update operation? Any specific exception as getOne() throws EntityNotFound exception. Incase of exception, will it return any entity from database?

Can anyone please help me with these doubts. I googled the but could not get ny satisfactory answers.

Comment: If it doesn't throw an exception it was succesful. It will throw a `DataAccessException` from Spring. Be aware that catching the exception and throw your own exception **might** interfere with proper transaction management and lead to weird errors.

Comment: so incase of exception, the returned entity will be null?

Comment: There is nothing being returned, an exception is being thrown.